# Determine representation matrix of orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-adjoint-operators, hermitian-matrices

Let $V=\mathbb C^2$, $\mathcal E$ be the standard basis of $V$ and let $$U = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{pmatrix}\in V | (1+i)z_1 + (3+2i)z_2 = 0 \right\}.$$ Finally let $p:V\to V$ be the orthogonal projection from $V$ to $U$ wrt the canoical scalar product on $V$. I'm trying to find that $A:=M_{\mathcal E}^{\mathcal E}(p)$, and I really do not know how. I could imagine that A is hermitian, or that I have to somehow construct a basis of U. How do I go about doing this? This has given me many troubles so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Since the problem involves complex numbers, I assume everywhere you say "orthogonal" you mean "unitary." In this case the canonical scalar product between two vectors $\vec{v}, \vec{w}$ is $\vec{v}^* \vec{w}$, where the asterisk denotes the complex conjugate transpose of a matrix.

$U$ is one-dimensional (i.e. all vectors in it point in the same direction), so finding an orthonormal basis for it is easy. Note that any vector of $U$ is of the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{pmatrix} = t\begin{pmatrix} 3 + 2i \\ -1 - i \end{pmatrix}$$
for some $t \in \mathbb{C}$. This is obtained just by solving the equation that vectors in $U$ satisfy. To find an orthonormal basis for $U$, we must find a vector of unit norm in $U$; this occurs when 
$$t = \left(|3 + 2i|^2 + |-1 - i|^2\right)^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}$$
From here, let us denote 
$$\vec{u} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 15}\begin{pmatrix} 3 + 2i \\ -1 - i \end{pmatrix}$$
which is the sole element of an orthonormal basis for $U$. The orthogonal projection of some vector $\vec{v} \in V$ onto $U$ is then given by
$$\text{proj}_{\vec{u}}(\vec{v}) = (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{u}) \vec{u} = \vec{u} \vec{u}^* \vec{v}$$
And hence we can see that the matrix representing the projection is given by 
$$A = \vec{u} \vec{u}^* = \frac{1}{15} \begin{pmatrix} 13 & 1 + 5i \\ 1 - 5i & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This is a lot more succinct than anything I have done so far, thank you. The only thing that doesn't make sense to me here is the first sentence,  'Since the problem involves complex numbers, I assume everywhere you say "orthogonal" you mean "unitary".' Why is this the case?

Comment: The word "orthogonal" is usually used when dealing with real matrices and vectors, while "unitary" is used when dealing with complex numbers. When complex numbers are introduced, some things must be altered: for example, when taking the magnitude of a vector $\vec{v}$, we must calculate $\vec{v}^* \vec{v}$ instead of $\vec{v}^T \vec{v}$. If we didn't then the magnitude of a nonzero vector, e.g. $(1, i)$ could be zero, which is not something we desire.